# How can I add a UISearchDisplayController to a UIView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

How can I add a UISearchDisplayController to a UIView? Interface builder won't let me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A UISearchDisplayController cannot be added to a UIView because it doesn't inherit from a UIView. You can add a UISearchBar in Interface builder with an IBOutlet and then create a UISearchDisplayController with that UISearchBar programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it in code e.g. (assuming the view controller is vc):

```
[vc addSubview:mySearchDisplayController.searchBar];
// Note that searchBar is the view, and mySearchDisplayController only CONTROLS the searchBar etc.
```